# Access data outside an asynchronous call?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I access the vehicle data and assign it to data.diff after? I tried accessing the vehicle out the function but it's empty.

Code

```
schema.methods.log = function (data) {

    let condition = { VIN: this.VIN }
    let Vehicle = keystone.list('Vehicle');

    async function myFunction() {
        const vehicle = await Vehicle.model.findOne(condition)
        if (vehicle) {
            console.log("vehicle", vehicle)
        }
    }

    //its empty
    console.log("vehicle", vehicle)

    data.diff = {
        before: this,
        after: vehicle,
    }

    myFunction()

    return LogSchema.create(data)
}
```

Comment: It's empty due to the fact that the async call has not completed yet and you accessing the data. Where is the `load()` function declaration? what is calling `myFunction()`

Comment: sorry  i was not able to update , wait ill update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```js
schema.methods.log = async function(data) {

    let condition = { VIN: this.VIN }
    let Vehicle = keystone.list('Vehicle');

    const vehicle = await Vehicle.model.findOne(condition);

    if (vehicle) {
        console.log("vehicle", vehicle)
        data.diff = {
            before: this,
            after: vehicle,
        }

        return LogSchema.create(data)
    } else {

        return "Some error message or object here...";

    }

}
```